# Overlap when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

[The sidebox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KJsk.jpg)

So I have a side box above which acts as a bill.

```
HTML
    </div>
<div id="crt_user">
    <h1>Summary: (Choose items )</h1>
    <p>Amt left in Wallet: 1234<br>
     <span id="left">Bill Amt:</span> 
     <!--the container where the price is shown-->
     <div id="tags">
         <span id="rupee" style="font-family: DejaVu Sans;">&#x20b9;</span>
        <div id="result">0</div>
    </div>  

     <button id="clear">Clear</button>
    </p>     
    </div>
```

The side box has the following css:

```
  /*#crt_user header and ruppe symbol */
#left {
position:absolute;
top:85%;
left:0%;
font-size:1rem;
}
#rupee {
position:absolute;
top:-10%;
left:0%;
}
#result {
  position:absolute;
  top:2%;
  left:10%;
  /* background-color: red; */
  height:90%;
  width:60%;
}
```

SO when one of the buttons below is clicked, the sidebox above dynamically shows the bill amount.

[the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB1g2.jpg)

Code for the buttons:

```
<button class="items" id="34">Pani Puri &emsp;  <span style="font-family: 
DejaVu Sans;">&#x20b9;</span>50</button> <br>
```

The js behind this is :

```
 function main() {
   var item=document.getElementsByClassName('items');
   var screen = document.getElementById("tags");
   var result = document.getElementById("result");
   var price=0;
    var prices =



[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42];

for(var i=0;i<item.length;i++) {
      item[i].addEventListener("click",function() {
           var e = parseInt(this.getAttribute('id'));
           console.log(prices[e]); 
            document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('id')).disabled =true;
            price += prices[e];
              screen.innerHTML = '<span id="rupee" style="font-family: 
          DejaVu Sans;">&#x20b9;</span>' +price;
     }); //end EventListener functionality
     }
 }
```

Yet this happens: 
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwjvS.jpg)

How do i fix this ?
[boundry of the box(height width)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzB16.jpg)

Comment: Please provide working code.

Comment: The whole code you mean  ?

Comment: Set up a fiddle or a local snippet so that we can easily understand, work and reproduce your case.

Comment: I cant create a fiddle the code is too big

Comment: What do you mean by local snippet

Comment: try better to explain what your issue is Gokul, we can't understand it if you do not post full example code

Comment: Plz take a look at the images that i have posted along with the question(links)

Comment: just to clarify the error occurs after clicking on the button

Comment: do you want to fix that overlapping, amount upon Rupee sign ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use &nbsp in after rupee sign span tag like below..

```
screen.innerHTML = '<span id="rupee" style="font-family: 
          DejaVu Sans;">&#x20b9;</span> &nbsp; &nbsp; ' +price;
```

or wrap price variable in span tag and give them left margin'

```
screen.innerHTML = '<span id="rupee" style="font-family: 
          DejaVu Sans;">&#x20b9;</span> <span style="margin-left:10px;">' +price+'</span>';
```